# Is it correct to write "sayd" instead of "said"?

Tags: verbs

The question arose because there is a [wiktionary entry for "sayd."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sayd)

Comment: I believe using "said" is the correct one.

Comment: As the wiktionary page mentions, "sayd" is archaic or dialectal. So you shouldn't use it in normal writing. (If you want to write some text with an archaic English flavor, though, then by all means. Throw in some "[thou](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thou)"s and "[doth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doth)"s as well. But use them correctly, or scholars will complain.)

Comment: Well, i understand, thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes.

The number of contexts where it will be interpreted as anything but a spelling error is very limited, however.  As wiktionary says, it's "archaic" and "obsolete."

It would, for instance, be fine in a story where characters were reading a document written several centuries earlier, and showing it by using archaic spellings.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably stick with "said," it's easier to understand and most modern English readers are used to it.